# After Friend request is accepted, do not display User (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a users-table where users can add each other as friends after the friend request is send I have it so that an icon appears which indicates that the request is pending,

now I tried to make it so that after the request is accepted the user no longer appears in the users-table, my code works on the sender side of things, after the request is accepted the user no longer appears in the table, but on the receiving side the added user still appear as add-able (also in both users friend-list)

(the view)

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" 
  onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <input placeholder="zoeken.."></input>

  </div>


 <div id="main">
 <span onclick="openNav()" ondblclick="closeNav()" style="float:left;z-
index:2;position:relative;top:10px;right:-5px;">
 <img src="images/icons/Zoekn.png" width="40" style="cursor:pointer;font-
  size:12pt;">
</span>


 <h1 class="gardenHeader"><b style="position:relative;left:0px;">De 
 Name of table</b>
 </h1>






 <div class="gardenTable">

 @if($users)


   @foreach($users as $user)

    @if($user->gender == 'man')



  <?php 





  if(!$check) { ?>

    <div class="gardenElementMale"><a style="text-decoration: none;" 
  href="/profile/{{$user->id}}"><img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar 
   }}" alt="User Image" class="gardenImage"></a>
    <a href=""><span title="Stuur een vlindr" class="send-vlindr"></span>
    </a>
    <a href=""><span title="Ik vind je leuk" class="send-heart"></span></a>
    <a href="{{url('../')}}/addFriend/{{$user->id}}"><span 
       title="Vriendschapsverzoek" class="add-friend "></span></a> 
     <a href="/profile/{{$user->id}}" style="text-decoration:none;"><h4 
     class="gardenName">{{$user->User}}  &#9794;</h4></a></div>


  <?php } elseif($status) { ?>
    <div class="gardenElementMale"><a style="text-decoration: none;" 
  href="/profile/{{$user->id}}"><img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar 
  }}" alt="User Image" class="gardenImage"></a>
    <a href=""><span title="Stuur een vlindr" class="send-vlindr"></span>
   </a>
    <a href=""><span title="Ik vind je leuk" class="send-heart"></span></a>
    <a href="/profile/{{$user->id}}"><span title="Vriendschapsverzoek is 
    verstuurd" class="pending"></span></a>

     <a href="/profile/{{$user->id}}" style="text-decoration:none;"><h4 
    class="gardenName">{{$user->User}}  &#9794;</h4></a></div>



   <?php } else { ?>


    <?php } ?>




    @else


    <?php 
    $check = DB::table('friendships')
    ->where('recipient_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->where('sender_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)

    ->first(); 

    $status = DB::table('friendships')
  ->where('recipient_id', '=', $user->id)
 ->where('sender_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)

 ->where('status', '=', '0')
 ->first();




  if(!$check) { ?>

    <div class="gardenElementFemale"><a style="text-decoration: none;" 
     href="/profile/{{$user->id}}"><img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user-
    >avatar }}" alt="User Image" class="gardenImage"></a>
    <a href=""><span title="Stuur een vlindr" class="send-vlindr"></span>
    </a>
    <a href=""><span title="Ik vind je leuk" class="send-heart"></span></a>
    <a href="{{url('../')}}/addFriend/{{$user->id}}"><span 
    title="Vriendschapsverzoek" class="add-friend "></span></a> 
     <a href="/profile/{{$user->id}}" style="text-decoration:none;"><h4 
    class="gardenName">{{$user->User}}  &#9794;</h4></a></div>


    <?php } elseif($status) { ?>
    <div class="gardenElementFemale"><a style="text-decoration: none;" 
     href="/profile/{{$user->id}}"><img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user-
     >avatar }}" alt="User Image" class="gardenImage"></a>
    <a href=""><span title="Stuur een vlindr" class="send-vlindr"></span>
     </a>
    <a href=""><span title="Ik vind je leuk" class="send-heart"></span></a>
    <a href="/profile/{{$user->id}}"><span title="Vriendschapsverzoek is 
     verstuurd" class="pending"></span></a>

     <a href="/profile/{{$user->id}}" style="text-decoration:none;"><h4 
      class="gardenName">{{$user->User}}  &#9794;</h4></a></div>



     <?php } else { ?>


       <?php } ?>


       @endif
         @endforeach

             @endif



   </div>
  <span style="">{{$users->links()}}</span>
  </div>
   @endsection
```

(My Controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Profile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use App\User;
use App\Friendships; 
use App\Traits\Friendable;
use DB;
use App\notifications;



class GardenController extends Controller
{


 use Friendable;


public function member(){

$users = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())-
>paginate(20);

return view('pages.garden', compact('users'));
}


 public function viewProfile($userId = null) {
    $user = null;

    if($userId != null) {
        $user = User::find($userId);
    } else {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    }

    return view('/profile', [
        'user' => $user
    ]);
   }



            public function sendRequest($id) {
                Auth::user()->addFriend($id);
                return back();
            }



                public function requests() {
                $uid = Auth::user()->id;
                $FriendRequests = DB::table('friendships')
                                ->rightJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 
  'friendships.sender_id')
                                ->where('status', '=', '0')
                                ->where('friendships.recipient_id', '=', 
   $uid)->get();
                return view('requests', compact('FriendRequests'));
            }



 public function accept($name, $id) {
     $uid = Auth::user()->id;
     $checkRequest = friendships::where('sender_id', $id)
            ->where('recipient_id', $uid)
            ->first();
    if ($checkRequest) {

        // echo "yes, update here";
        $updateFriendship = DB::table('friendships')
                ->where('recipient_id', $uid)
                ->where('sender_id', $id)
                ->update(['status' => 1]);

        $notifications = new notifications;
        $notifications->note = 'Vriendschapsverzoek is geaccepteerd';
        $notifications->user_hero = $id; // who is accepting my request
        $notifications->user_logged = Auth::user()->id; // me
        $notifications->status = '1'; // unread notifications
        $notifications->save();
        if ($notifications) {
            return back()->with('msg', 'U bent nu bevriend met ' . $name);
        }
    } else {
        return back()->with('msg', 'U bent nu bevriend met dit lid');
    }
    }

                            public function friends() {

                                    $uid = Auth::user()->id;
                                    $friends1 = DB::table('friendships')
                                            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 
  'friendships.recipient_id') // who is not loggedin but send request to
                                            ->where('status', 1)
                                            ->where('sender_id', $uid) // 
who is logged in
                                            ->get();
                                    //dd($friends1);
                                     $friends2 = DB::table('friendships')
                                            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 
'friendships.sender_id')
                                            ->where('status', 1)
                                            ->where('recipient_id', $uid)
                                            ->get();
                                    $friends = array_merge($friends1-
  >toArray(), $friends2->toArray());
                                    return view('/friends', 
compact('friends'));
                    }


    public function requestRemove($id) {
            DB::table('friendships')
            ->where('recipient_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('sender_id', $id)
            ->delete();
            return back()->with('msg', 'Vriendschapsverzoek is 
   verwijderd.');
   }

 public function notifications($id) {
     $uid = Auth::user()->id;
                             $notes = DB::table('notifications')
                                    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 
'notifications.user_logged')
                                    ->where('notifications.id', $id)
                                    ->where('user_hero', $uid)
                                    ->orderBy('notifications.created_at', 
  'desc')
                                       ->get();
        $updateNoti = DB::table('notifications')
                     ->where('notifications.id', $id)
                    ->update(['status' => 0]);
       return view('notifications', compact('notes'));
    }

 }
```

(trait-model-)

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;
use App\Friendships;
trait Friendable {

public function addFriend($id){

    $Friendship = friendships::create([

        'sender_id' => $this->id, // who is logged in
        'recipient_id' => $id,
    ]);

    if($Friendship)
    {

        return $Friendship;
    }

    return 'failed';

}

}
```

(model)

```
 <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Friendships extends Model
{

   protected $fillable = ['sender_id', 'sender_type', 'recipient_id', 
   'recipient_type', 'status',];
 }
```

(User model)

```
namespace App;
use App\Traits\Friendable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Friendships;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;



 class User extends Authenticatable
   {
   use Notifiable;

   use Friendable;




/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'dob', 'gender', 'email', 'woonplaats', 'User', 'avatar', 
 'password',
   ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
     * @var array
    */
     protected $hidden = [
      'password', 'remember_token',
   ];

public function posts(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function friends()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Friendships');
}

    }
```

Comment: your code is really messy, create a controller, and then a view using blade templating so the code is easier to read

Comment: Don't do database queries in a loop, this will create way too many database requests. Can you show the controller code that loads the `$users`? That is what should be changed.

Comment: this is in my Controller it loads all the users into the user-section,

     public function member(){

         $users = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())-
         >paginate(20);

       return view('pages.garden', compact('users'));
       }

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code. Also, does your `User` model have a `friends` relation?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the query in your controller to exclude friends using the [`whereDoesntHave`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) function.

```
User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())
    ->whereDoesntHave('friends', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', Auth::id());
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: it gives me a

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::friends()

Comment: Do you have a relation on you `User` model for friends?

Comment: I have in my User model an App\Friendships; relation (?)

Comment: You are currently not using the relations like Laravel intends you to. You should consider taking a look at the documentation of relations to put relations between your models, this will make it so much more easy to create complex queries as the example above. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I've added the relation to my User Model,

but now I get 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'friendships.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `id` != 1 and not exists (select * from `friendships` where `users`.`id` = `friendships`.`user_id` and `id` = 1))

Help please? (reading as much as I can, didn't figure it out yet)